# Cross Tab Query in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm having to apply a cross-tab query on two of my tables to get desired results. (MS-ACCESS) I would first like to learn how to write a cross-tab query on a simple table before moving on to the bigger one.

Table 1:

```
**DATE** |       **NAME**   
-------------------------------------
 13/12/16  |    Sofia    
 13/12/16  |     Sonia  
 13/12/16  |     Jas    
 14/12/16  | Sofia  
 15/12/16  | Sonia
```

Desired result:  (P = Present; A = Absent)

```
**Name** | **13/12/16** | **14/12/16** | **15/12/16**  
--------------------------------------------------------
Sofia | **P** | **P** | **A**  
Sonia | **P** | **A** | **P**   
Jas   | **P** | **A** | **A**
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach cross-tab queries is to use conditional aggregation:

```
select name,
       max(iif(date = "13/12/16", "P", "A") as [13/12/16],
       max(iif(date = "14/12/16", "P", "A") as [14/12/16],
       max(iif(date = "15/12/16", "P", "A") as [15/12/16]
from t
group by name;
```

I'm not sure how the dates are represented in the data, so I just assumed they are strings.

Comment: Thankyou so much. What will I have to do if say, for the month of December, I need 31 date columns (irrespective of whether they are present in the first table or not) plus a name column and the rowns have names and either 'P' or 'A' if that particular date and name are present in table 1?

Comment: @SofiaUsman . . . Just repeat the `max()` lines for every date you want.

Comment: Did we forget MS Access SQL does not support `Case` statements?

Comment: @Parfait what's the alternative?